# Regenerate thumbnails without a WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails

I'm working on my first WordPress plugin, and I've added new image sizes that the user can choose for uploaded images to be used as ads on the site. But if there are existing images in the Media Library when the plugin is activated, the image thumbnails will need to be regenerated. I'm looking for a way to add this functionality to my plugin without the user needing to install another plugin to do it manually.

I cannot seem to find a way to do this programmatically for a single image—the one selected by the user to be used as an ad.

Answer (score 1):

There's a native regenerate thumbnail feature for woocommerce. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I'd like to add it to my own plugin without the need for other plugins or manual work. But I wasn't aware of the WooCommerce feature. Maybe I can look at the code there for inspiration.